# openstack service failed when creating the password plugin

Tags: openstack, centos7

I installed openstack through packstack. However I am having a tough time dealing with the commands.

```
 openstack service list --long
```

I get:

> Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating
>   the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL. Unable
>   to establish connection to http://10.23.77.68:5000/v2.0/tokens

10.23.77.68 is my controller node

I ran another command for the neutron, gave me the same response. Kindly help. Absolutely new in this arena.

I do not know what logs to paste, as I am very new,but you can let me know. However I can start with nova-api.log

> 2016-06-26 21:48:54.675 7560 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server
>   [req-fdf8e231-59b3-46f7-b988-57e7be7d5e17
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 - -
>   -] 10.23.77.68 "GET /v2/1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336/servers/detail HTTP/1.1" status:
>   200 len: 15838 time: 0.5084898 2016-06-26 21:53:54.151 7535 INFO
>   nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server
>   [req-5dd24a35-fb47-45d6-94da-19303e27a95b
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 - -
>   -] 10.23.77.68 "GET /v2/1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 HTTP/1.1" status: 404 len: 264 time: 0.2648351 2016-06-26 21:53:54.167 7535 INFO
>   nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server
>   [req-a5eac33d-660c-41a5-8269-2ba8c3063984
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 - -
>   -] 10.23.77.68 "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 573 time: 0.0116799 2016-06-26 21:53:55.033 7535 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server
>   [req-2eeb31d2-947e-45be-bfb8-b8f8ebf602b8
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 - -
>   -] 10.23.77.68 "GET /v2/1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336/servers/detail HTTP/1.1" status:
>   200 len: 15838 time: 0.6974850

EDIT :

`/var/log/keystone.log` is

> [root@controller ~]# tail /var/log/keystone/keystone.log 2016-06-29
>   15:11:21.975 22759 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-ce18ee5e-2323-4f7a-937c-71cb3b96e9a0
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/v2.0/users 2016-06-29
>   15:11:21.976 22759 WARNING oslo_log.versionutils
>   [req-ce18ee5e-2323-4f7a-937c-71cb3b96e9a0
>   765512ebca194201b741a9688e07b598 1a7f14a22e56468fa12ebe04ef7ee336 -
>   default default] Deprecated: get_users of the v2 API is deprecated as
>   of Mitaka in favor of a similar function in the v3 API and may be
>   removed in Q. 2016-06-29 15:11:36.526 22854 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-a63438d5-603e-423f-8c9d-25cf44ac12dc - - - - -] GET
>   http://10.23.77.68:35357/ 2016-06-29 15:11:36.536 28937 INFO
>   keystone.common.wsgi [req-177f988e-43ac-49ee-bf9a-e12084646f28 - - - -
>   -] POST http://10.23.77.68:35357/v2.0/tokens 2016-06-29 15:11:36.682 28393 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-48ccc8d8-e9cb-4e1e-b8bc-ceba9139d654
>   f93c5815f49342c8809ed489801ae9e1 b0d28d12a3814157b93b5badf9340d1f -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/v3/auth/tokens
>   2016-06-29 15:11:37.047 22096 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-98c1fd31-e5b5-48e8-afd6-8d635ae4cb6a
>   85c9b4514a3042f991cb00c8b1a5b3ca b0d28d12a3814157b93b5badf9340d1f -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/ 2016-06-29 15:11:37.056
>   25970 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-971dd038-0433-4d36-a341-654a0f421472 - - - - -] POST
>   http://10.23.77.68:35357/v2.0/tokens 2016-06-29 15:11:37.182 24078
>   INFO keystone.common.wsgi [req-33cd309d-38c3-4faa-acfb-4406708cd6c8
>   85c9b4514a3042f991cb00c8b1a5b3ca b0d28d12a3814157b93b5badf9340d1f -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/v3/auth/tokens
>   2016-06-29 15:12:23.884 22587 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-44e1df97-e487-4e82-9293-c1344d0cbaef
>   85c9b4514a3042f991cb00c8b1a5b3ca b0d28d12a3814157b93b5badf9340d1f -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/v3/auth/tokens
>   2016-06-29 15:12:27.816 27690 INFO keystone.common.wsgi
>   [req-0755f2a0-8280-4567-af0f-270df896e6f6
>   85c9b4514a3042f991cb00c8b1a5b3ca b0d28d12a3814157b93b5badf9340d1f -
>   default default] GET http://10.23.77.68:35357/v3/auth/tokens
>   [root@controller ~]#

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell which version of Openstack are you ruuning ? Liberty or Mitaka ?

Also at what stage did the installation stop ?

Source the keystonerc_admin file. This file contains the credentials that will give you access to using these commands/APIs

command: source

Comment: Installation completed. using packstack. Dashboard works fine. Openstack Mitaka. Problem with the command line.

Comment: Did you source the keystonerc_admin file ? A file named keystonerc_admin will be created that will contain the credentials for Openstack.

Comment: Please use the command source <keystonerc_admin file name> and try again.

Comment: even  "neutron subnet-list" gives the same error :( all the commands I try give this error :(

Comment: ask your questions in comment not in answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use `curl http://10.23.77.68:5000` on your controller ndoe, if it successfully return version list, then keystone service is ok, you need to check the connect between control node and other nodes, otherwise, you need to check keystone log in 10.23.77.68, it seems this service is not running

Comment: This HTML thing I got as output. Just removed some HTML tags to show O/P

<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>

<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
For assistance, contact your network support team.

Comment: you need to check keystone log, mostly keystone-api is run in apache with mod_wsgi, then it can be found in /var/log/apache2/keystone.log , maybe you need to check apache error log as well

Comment: edited the answer to show the keystone logs. However couldn't find any apache2 folder.

Answer (score -2):

Have you try restarting the httpd service and memcached?

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```